# repetitive value assignment in a while loop, Python

Tags: python, while-loop

Please look at following while loop code written in Python:

```
x=25
epsilon=0.01 
high=max(1.0,x)
low=0.0
*ans=(low+high)/2.0*

while abs(ans**2-x)>=epsilon:
    if ans2>x:
        high=ans
    else:
        low=ans
   *ans = (high + low)/2.0*
print("ans:",ans,)
```

This is a guess loop (exhaustion), it should find the approx for square root of a positive number within the margin error on 0,01. 
But I cant understand why we must define ans (ans=(low+high)/2.0) the second time, first before the loop and then again in the loop.  Could someone tell me what purpose the second definition have since im seeing the first one being enough?

Thanks
Arif

Comment: If ans does not change, i.e. the 2nd definition, then you will have an infinite while loop (all of the variables remain the same).  And you use ans2 > x in the if statement.  Neither of these variables changes so will yield the same result on every pass through the while loop, i.e. will not give a good result.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you need to perform that calculation on each iteration of the loop including the very first iteration. Since your while test is the very first part of the loop, you need to do it once before the loop starts.

Here's a way to do it with just one statement:

```
while True:
   *ans = (high + low)/2.0*
    if abs(ans**2-x)>=epsilon:
        break
    if ans2>x:
        high=ans
    else:
        low=ans
```